Can I find from which directory a command was executed?
A command find . -type f  was issued on one of our servers by one of our users and its currently running when viewed in ps aux.
How can I know from which directory was this command issued.
Does that process has env variable like current working directory that I can retrieve to get what I want or anything like that?
Note: The  above command is contrived and actual commad is something else. But is it possible to find which directory it was issued

ls -l /proc/PID/cwd where PID is the right PID. Still, I think find is allowed to change its current working directory during its run, as long as the results are within specification; so what you get may or may not be what you seek. Therefore this is just a comment, not an answer.

You can use the pwdx command which is designed specifically for this purpose to report the current working directory of a process.

In ps aux you can easily find the PID of this one using ps aux | grep "find . -type f" (or if you have it already)
Use this PID with pwdx <PID>

You can also make it in one run as:
pwdx $(ps aux | grep '[f]ind . -type f' | awk '{print $2}')


Another way to do it (useful for some systems that don't come with pwdx but do have ls) can be what @Kamil Maciorowski mentioned in the comments:
ls -l /proc/<PID>/cwd


As pointed out by Ysroel Tech, one could use either the pwdx <PID> or ls -l /proc/<PID>/cwd
while the process is being run.
I personally prefer the latter.
If the process has already finished, this will serve no purpose and you can try to go through journactl logs for the time interval you know the command was issued e.g journalctl --since "2024-09-27 00:00:00" --until "2024-09-27 <time command stopped>" with no guarantee that the command will be found if no kind of log audit method was set.
There may be other ways that I'm unaware of, but I do recommend you implement a method to do it.
